# jquery bind .load call with .trigger

Tags: jquery

I feel like I'm just searching for the wrong keywords in google and on here.  I just can't seem to find the right answer to this. Or maybe I have and wasn't sure what I was reading.

I'm trying to load a div with data via a .load call.  Then later on in my script when I click a button, I want to trigger that load again.

`$j("#adminList").bind("load", function("categories.php", { action:"get" }){} );
$j("#button").click( function(){ $j("#adminList").trigger("load"); });`

That's a shortened code, but that gives you an example of what I'm trying to do.

Right now, I get a missing formal parameter error on the function.

Thanks for the help1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding to the load event is probably not what you want.
Simplify this by making a function that calls $.load() and then call this new function in your click event and anywhere else you need it.

Example

```
function loadAdminList() {
  $("#adminList").load("categories.php", function (responseText, textStatus, xhr) {
     //Handle/Manipulate the return value here 
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function() {
    loadAdminList();
  });
});
```

Comment: This is the right answer.  What is up with the, "You can accept this answer in 6 minutes" message that appears when I try to accept an answer?

Comment: Oh by the way...how simple.  Gosh, sometimes I guess we just make things complicated :)

Answer (score 1):

this should do it.

```
$(function(){
    $('#adminList').load("categories.php", {action:'GET'});
    $('#button').click(function(){
        $('#adminList').load("categories.php", {action:'GET'});
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$j("#button")
         .click( 
                function(){ $j('#adminList').load("categories.php", { action:"get" }); }
               )
         .click();
```

the first `click(..)` binds your handler and the second (*without params*) invokes it the first time.